# Verify transmit power to be within certain limits of its expected value over 95% of test measurements

Tags: statistics, probability, distribution, normal-distribution

I have a requirement where I have to verify the transmit power out of a device as measured at its connector is within 2 dB of its expected value over 95% of test measurements.

I am using a signal analyzer to analyze the transmitted power. I only get the average power value, min, max and stdDev of the measurements and not the individual power measurements.

Now, the question is how would I verify the "95% thing" using average power, min, max and stdDev. It seems that I can use normal distribution to find the 95% confidence level.

I would appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about statistics and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm reading this, it seems you are a statistical beginner, so if I'm wrong there, the rest of this answer will probably be insultingly basic, and I'm sorry.

Anyway, the idea is that if a dataset is normally distributed, and all the observations are independent of one another, then 95% of the data points will fall within 1.96 standard deviations of the mean.

Do you get identical estimates of average power every time you measure, or are there some slight random differences from reading to reading?  My guess is that it's the second. If you were to measure the power a whole bunch of times, and each time you plotted your average power value on a histogram, then that histogram of sample means would have the shape of a bell curve. This bell curve of sample means would have its own mean and standard deviation, and if you have thousands or millions of data points going into the calculation of each average power reading, it's not horrible to assume that it is a normal distribution.   The explanation for this phenomenon is known as the 'central limit theorem', and I recommend both the [Khan academy's presentation of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNm3M9cqWyc) as well as [the wikipedia page on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem).

On the other hand, if your average power is the mean of some small number of data points, like for instance n=  5, or n= 30, then assumption of a normal distribution of sample means can be pretty bad. In this case, your 95% confidence interval around the average power goes from qt(0.975,n-1)*SD/sqrt(n) below the average to qt(0.975,n-1)*SD/sqrt(N) above the average, where qt(0.975,n-1) is the 97.5th percentile of the t distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom, and SD is your measured standard deviation.

Comment: That's not what the central limit theorem says.  The CLT talks about the distributional behavior of sums of X's (which are the basis of calculating the average, a.k.a. the sample mean). If the underlying distribution of the X's is exponential, for instance, a histogram if your data will look more and more exponential as you get more observations. It doesn't magically transform to become normal.

Comment: Woh, don't shoot! I completely agree that an exponential distribution will not become normal, no matter how many samples you take of it. I wasn't saying it would. What I am claiming is that the distribution of *sample means* taken from any statistical distribution will become approximately normal with enough samples, and that this result follows from the central limit theorem.

Comment: I think your answer is unclear as written, and still not technically correct since normality is the limiting distribution of the sample means as the sample size *per sample mean* increases, not as the number of sample means increases.  Please edit your answer to be a bit clearer.